# opengl animations slow down when window size is increased

Tags: c, opengl

In many OpenGL tutorials, e.g. [swiftless tutorials](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/rotation.html) and many others, whenever there is an animation in the scene and the window is resized, the speed of the animation changes.

**Description of strange behaviour**

- when the window is small, the animation speeds up

  when the window is large the animation slows down

Is there an explanation for this?

```
#include <GL/glew.h> // Include the GLEW header file  
#include <GL/glut.h> // Include the GLUT header file  

bool* keyStates = new bool[256]; // Create an array of boolean values of length 256 (0-255)  

bool movingUp = false; // Whether or not we are moving up or down  
float yLocation = 0.0f; // Keep track of our position on the y axis.  

float yRotationAngle = 0.0f; // The angle of rotation for our object  

void keyOperations (void) {  
    if (keyStates[GLUT_KEY_LEFT]) { // If the left arrow key has been pressed  
        // Perform left arrow key operations  
    }  
}  

void display (void) {  
    keyOperations();  

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Clear the background of our <a title="window" href="http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/window.html">window</a> to red  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Clear the colour buffer (more buffers later on)  
    glLoadIdentity(); // Load the Identity Matrix to reset our drawing locations  

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f); // Push eveything 5 units back into the scene, otherwise we won't see the primitive  

    glTranslatef(0.0f, yLocation, 0.0f); // Translate our object along the y axis  

    glRotatef(yRotationAngle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Rotate our object around the y axis  

    glutWireCube(2.0f); // Render the primitive  

    glFlush(); // Flush the OpenGL buffers to the window  

    if (movingUp) // If we are moving up  
        yLocation -= 0.005f; // Move up along our yLocation  
    else  // Otherwise  
        yLocation += 0.005f; // Move down along our yLocation  

    if (yLocation < -3.0f) // If we have gone up too far  
        movingUp = false; // Reverse our direction so we are moving down  
    else if (yLocation > 3.0f) // Else if we have gone down too far  
        movingUp = true; // Reverse our direction so we are moving up  

    yRotationAngle += 0.005f; // Increment our rotation value  

    if (yRotationAngle > 360.0f) // If we have rotated beyond 360 degrees (a full rotation)  
        yRotationAngle -= 360.0f; // Subtract 360 degrees off of our rotation  
}  

void reshape (int width, int height) {  
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height); // Set our viewport to the size of our window  
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // Switch to the projection matrix so that we can manipulate how our scene is viewed  
    glLoadIdentity(); // Reset the projection matrix to the identity matrix so that we don't get any artifacts (cleaning up)  

    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0, 100.0); // Set the Field of view angle (in degrees), the aspect ratio of our window, and the new and far planes  

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // Switch back to the model view matrix, so that we can start drawing shapes correctly  
}  

void keyPressed (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {  
    keyStates[key] = true; // Set the state of the current key to pressed  
}  

void keyUp (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {  
    keyStates[key] = false; // Set the state of the current key to not pressed  
}  

int main (int argc, char **argv) {  
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // Initialize GLUT  
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE); // Set up a basic display buffer (only single buffered for now)  
    glutInitWindowSize (500, 500); // Set the width and height of the window  
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100); // Set the position of the window  
    glutCreateWindow ("You’re first OpenGL Window"); // Set the title for the window  

    glutDisplayFunc(display); // Tell GLUT to use the method "display" for rendering  

    glutIdleFunc(display); // Tell GLUT to use the method "display" as our idle method as well  

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); // Tell GLUT to use the method "reshape" for reshaping  

    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed); // Tell GLUT to use the method "keyPressed" for key presses  
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyUp); // Tell GLUT to use the method "keyUp" for key up events  

    glutMainLoop(); // Enter GLUT's main loop  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way this is written it uses an "as fast as possible" rendering approach. This, together with V-Sync disabled will make the animation speed depend on the time it takes to calculate the pixels of one frame. The larger the window, the more pixels there are to fill (look up the keyword *fillrate*).

The solution is, to measure the time between rendering frames and advance the animation by this.